# powershell Find and replace text in a config file

Tags: powershell

I have a config file with text within which i would like to replace.

The text in the config file looks like the following

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <applicationSettings>
      <setting name="ExtendTimeMins" serializeAs="String">
        <value>5</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DisableHotkeySupport" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ServerPingInterval" serializeAs="String">
        <value>00:00:10</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DirectorySweepRate" serializeAs="String">
        <value>00:10:00</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="StopSignalExitDelaySecs" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
```

I want to change the False value of DisableHotkeySupport to True, but not change the StopSignalExitDelaySecs value.

Does anyone have any advice how to do this.

Comment: That looks like XML. Is the whole config file valid XML?

Comment: Yes it is
Top line of the file is 
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

Comment: If this is an XML file, use PowerShell's XML functionality. `$xml = [xml](Get-Content -Path '.\file.xml'`

Comment: In that case you'll want to parse it as XML (`[xml](Get-Content .\path\to\file.config -Raw)`), that way you can start working with it programmatically

Comment: Thanks, i am pretty much a novice when it comes to powershell, if you could point me in the right direction where to start that would be great.

Comment: I have edited the code correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for showing the entire config XML

To change the `<Value>False</Value>` into `<Value>True</Value>` for just the setting with `name="DisableHotkeySupport"` do not try to use text replacements, but instead:

```
$file = 'X:\TheConfigFile.config'  # full path to your config file goes here
# load the file in a new XmlDocument object
$xml = [System.XML.XMLDocument]::new()
$xml.Load($file)
($xml.configuration.applicationSettings.setting | Where-Object { $_.name -eq 'DisableHotkeySupport' }).Value = 'True'
# save the updated file
$xml.Save($file)
```

Comment: Thank you, that is perfect, do you know how you would check the value in a if statement.

If (($xml.configuration.applicationSettings.setting | Where-Object { $_.name -eq 'DisableHotkeySupport' }).Value = 'False')
}
write-host "True"
}
else
{
Write-Host "False"
}

Would this work?

Comment: @unitechie Well, sure, but wouldn't that become confusing to output  'True' when the value found is 'False' ? Anyway, just try it and see what gets returned. BTW. Being new to the platform you may not know this but it is customary to mark the question 'done' by clicking the large checkmark icon to the left of the answer. This helps others with a similar question finding it more easily.

Comment: Following your code above, i think i managed to check with an if statement as well, it might not be the best way to do it though.

$file = 'X:\TheConfigFile.config'  # full path to your config file goes here
# load the file in a new XmlDocument object
$xml = [System.XML.XMLDocument]::new()
$xml.Load($file)
$xmlvalue=($xml.configuration.applicationSettings.setting | Where-Object { $_.name -eq 'DisableHotkeySupport' }).Value
If ( "True" -eq $xmlvalue)
{
return $true
}
else
{
return $false
}

Sorry cant seem to work out how to block code in replies

Answer (score 0):

The same answer although using a somewhat different syntax...

```
[xml]($config = @'
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <applicationSettings>
      <setting name="ExtendTimeMins" serializeAs="String">
        <value>5</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DisableHotkeySupport" serializeAs="String">
        <value>False</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="ServerPingInterval" serializeAs="String">
        <value>00:00:10</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="DirectorySweepRate" serializeAs="String">
        <value>00:10:00</value>
      </setting>
      <setting name="StopSignalExitDelaySecs" serializeAs="String">
        <value>0</value>
      </setting>
  </applicationSettings>
</configuration>
'@)

$setting = $config.configuration.applicationSettings.setting | 
where name -eq 'DisableHotkeySupport'

$setting.Value = 'True'

$config.Save('mydata.xml')
```